# Potential memory leak in this Java code that produces out of heap error

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I can't find the reason why this piece of code when run for a long time produces an out of memory heap error. It runs constantly for 1-2 days before crashing. Can anyone see anything?
I only call a static function from another class that should not keep any resources open and then the mysql stuff but I close them all.

note: some of the variable names were changed.

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String ...args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Data.connectDb(); //init

try {

    List<Integer> written = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection con = Data.getConnection();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table2 LIMIT 500");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Integer mId = rs.getInt("mId");
        written.add(mId);
    }

    Map<Integer,String> bs = new HashMap<>();
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM b");
    while (rs.next()) {
        bs.put(rs.getInt("bId"),rs.getString("name"));
    }
    st.close();
    rs.close();

    while (true) {
        List<String> abers = new ArrayList<>();
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE enabled = 1");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            abers.add(email);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();

        ArrayList<Map> abs = Aber.getAbs(false);
        ArrayList<Map> toDispatch = new ArrayList<>();


        arbs.forEach((ab) -> {
            Integer mId = (Integer) ab.get("mId");
            if (!written.contains(mId)) {
                written.add(mId);
                toDispatch.add(arb);
                Pair hLine = (Pair) ab.get("hLine");
                Pair dLine = (Pair) ab.get("dLine");
                Pair aLine = (Pair) ab.get("aLine");
                //todo write it to the database not caring if it's already there as we have a unique constraint
                try (Statement st2 = con.createStatement()) {
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO table1")";
                    st2.executeUpdate(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        if (toDispatch.size() >0) {

            Email email = new Email();

            abes.forEach(arber -> email.addRecipient(aber, aber, Message.RecipientType.BCC));

            String HTML = "<h3>Dear subscribers</h3>";
            email.setTextHTML(HTML);

            new Mailer(
                    new ServerConfig("mail.name.com", 587, "info@mm.com", "mmpass"),
                    TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS
            ).sendMail(email);

        }

        Thread.sleep(600000);
    }
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler, don't guess things. Guessing is for people who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: Also never print out the `getMessage();` of an exception. Use `printStackTrace();` (as is done in the other catch blocks).

Comment: check what that Mailer is doing as well, maybe something is preventing each Mailer object to be garbage collected, or better create Mailer once if possible

Comment: Use the Memory Analysis tool.

Comment: @Kayaman I am not experienced with profilers. I am running Visual VM and it shows that by time the heap is growing but I get that I have a lot of byte[],char[] and treemap classes open.

Comment: @arisalexis Well the `byte[]` and `char[]` are the building blocks that use the memory. You'll want to look for the "higher" classes that are building up. If you've got 1000 `Statement` objects, you need to worry about that. Get to know your profiler.